# htaccess redirect language specific domains to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two old domains http://example1.com (**English**) and http://example2.com (**French**) and would like them to redirect to my new domain such as:

> http://example1.com => http://newdomain.com/en/
>
> http://example2.com => http://newdomain.com/fr/

Also I want to make sure the permalinks remain the same after redirecting as well.

E.g. http://example1.com/test.html => http://newdomain.com/en/test.html

**My Code:**

The below code fails to maintain the permalinks, also I am not sure how to add the french domain in the check.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As for keeping the permalinks, I don't think you can do it here, you'll have to do it in the new domain's `.htaccess`.

What do you use for translation ? Does it accept query parameters or is able to parse the uri by itself ?

Comment: It breaks at http://example2.com/ABC/324 also the ENV:LANG tag does not populate the variable. As per your question, I want to concatenate anything after the domain to the new.

Comment: @ZainKhan `LANG` is an already existing environment variable. However, even changing it, looks like it can't be used in external redirects. More testing required

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/fr%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to keep these rules as your **top rules** before other rules and you test in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: What about the following case http://example1.com/ABC/4314. This won't be handling the second /

Comment: As per these rules `http://example1.com/ABC/4314` would be redirected to `http://www.newdomain.com/en/ABC/4314`

Comment: Is that not what you expected?

Comment: Yes that is what I expect, but I tried your rules for the above case and they return http://example1.com/ABC/4314 rather than the new address

Comment: Yes exactly below **Rewrite Engine On**

Comment: ok can you place your complete .htaccess in question with `VirtualHost` config of `example1` and `example2` sites.